# What's the proper course of action here?

Tags: discussion, editing, edit-history

There has been some dispute in the revisions on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2109463/revisions) answer. First, someone edited it to add the word positive, then somebody made it bold, the somebody reverted that, I reverted back to the bold (which was approved) then somebody reverted to it without the word positive at all.

What is the proper course of action here? Which edit makes the most sense?

Comment: I would say that the latest edit is the best, perfect square are square of integers.

Comment: @JohnMa, but $-1$ is an integer, so just saying it's reserved for integers makes the answer conflict with itself saying $-1$ *is* a perfect square, then explaining why it usually *isn't*

Comment: @Travis Well and $3$ is a **positive** integer. The addition of positive misses the point. It is reserved for integers in the sense that it is reserved for numbers that are squares of integers (positive or not, though it does not really matter, except, for a nit-pick, I'd say $0$ is a perfect square so positive is somewhat false even.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the specific case: seconding John Ma, the last edit (by Will R.) actually clarifies the situation. The earlier addition(s) of "positive" however was besides the point.

For the general question: there is no point in engaging in back-and-forth editing. It's just noise.

Stop editing around (everybody). In case there is a conflict, make your case in a comment and try to find a resolution together. For instance a version superior to either of the conflicting versions (as in the present case). If no resolution among the parties involved is possible, flag for moderator attention, flag "other," explain the situation and move on.